# What happends if "false", "null" or something similar is added to backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

How will Backbone collections behave if I try to add false, undefined or null -kind of values in them? What events will they trigger?

Comment: Have you tried adding false, undefined or null?

Comment: Yes. It seems to work, but I wonder what happends underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a model is added to a collection thru **add/set** methods, it iterates thru the passed in array and for each element it tries to assign the element passed or an empty object for that element:

**From the Source Code:**

```
//Inside the set method of Backbone.Collection
for (i = 0, l = models.length; i < l; i++) {
    attrs = models[i] || {};

// Called internally by set method for each new item passed.
_prepareModel: function(attrs, options) {
  if (attrs instanceof Model) return attrs;
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  options.collection = this;
  var model = new this.model(attrs, options);
  if (!model.validationError) return model;
  this.trigger('invalid', this, model.validationError, options);
  return false;
}
```

Hence for undefined,null and false an empty object is created.

The set method then internally calls the _prepareModel method for each new item passed in the array. This creates a new instance of the backbone model passing the attrs object of the passed in item which is copied to the model. Since attrs is empty object (for null,undefined,false) no new properties are added in this case.

**add method (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add)** :

**add event is raised** for each new element.If **{merge: true}** is passed, then appropriate **change events** will be raised.

**set method (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set)** :

In case of **set method** appropriate **"add", "remove", and "change" events are fired** based on the passed in data.

For the given data(undefined,null,false e.t.c) add event will be triggered since new objects are created every time its added to the collection.